# Finding position of 2d list

Tags: python

So at the moment I'm just using a for loop, but my code has some many for loops within for loops I'm trying to see if theres a better way.

I have a list which looks like this (Truncated for example purposes):

```
bigram_list = [['go', 21364], ['oo', 34154], ['og', 20462]]
```

At the moment I run a for loop though the list to see if my input matches any of the strings, and if so gives me the values associated with said string.

```
bigram_list = [['go', 21364], ['oo', 34154], ['og', 20462]]
search_string = 'go'

for a in xrange(len(bigram_list)):
    if search_string in bigram_list[a][0]:
        print bigram_list[a][1]
```

I was wondering if theres a better way to do the above without a for loop?

Comment: *gives me the values associated with said string* - what should be the result?

Comment: There are several different ways to do this. Do you make this list yourself or is it supplied to you?

Comment: I also make the list myself from a previous for loop @roganjosh

Comment: In which case, is it instead possible to create a dictionary instead of a nested list? Something like `{'go': 21364, ...}` etc beforehand? If you can, it kills the problem at the source.

Comment: Yes I don't see why not, but why if I may ask? How so? @roganjosh

Comment: Because dictionary lookups are _much_ faster than searching through a list. They're analogous to real-life dictionaries. Imagine you're looking for a word, you can get to it super-quick if it's in alphabetical order (a dictionary) as opposed to it being in a scrambled order in which you have to read every single word for a match (a list).

Comment: In fact, a computer doesn't even need to hone in on a word like a normal dictionary; it's either there or it isn't, using the hash of the value. As to how you make it, we'd need to see your code that currently creates `bigram_list`.

Comment: Honestly, this has made my whole project so much easier and I'm not sure why I choose list in the first place. Just switched it to dictionary and its runs much faster and also was able to take the for loop away. Thank you for taking your time to explain and question. @roganjosh

Comment: You are more than welcome, glad it helped.